# Swift 3 -Flip entire screen/view On Orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to a way to constantly monitor if the user has rotated the iPad.

```
UserDidRotate() {

    if(orientation = portrait.upsideDown){

        //
        //Code that will Present View upside down...
        //
    }
        else if(orientation = portrait){

        //
        //Code that will Present View right side up...
        //
    }
}
```

How can I check for orientation change and also manually present the view upside down for my Swift 3 app?

EDIT:

I have tried:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: 
UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){}
```

and that method is never hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
self.view.transform = self.view.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI))
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the orientation problem.  Do you know a way that I can call that any time the user rotates the device?

Comment: @objectivelyC Since iOS app can handle the orientation rotation automatically, you should not need to do it manually.